# How to decode ASN.1 Per in Android?

Tags: android, hex, nfc, decoding, asn.1

I have a binary or hex decimal information which is encoded using the ASN.1 PER aligned and unaligned type(ASN.1 PER ISO 8825-2) from an NFC tag.

Is there any library supports the encoding and decoding of this data for android?

How to convert the binary information to string?

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/Tools.aspx for a list of ASN.1 Tools (some free, some commercial).  I know that some of the commercial tools listed there support encoding/decoding on Android platforms.